# ionic/AngularJS OK in Chrome, Can't find variable :$ in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Im currently using Ionic framework (inc AngularJS) with PhoneGap to develop a mobile application.
When running in chrome the application works seamlessly (I have been debugging the errors while in development).

I deployed to the iOS simulator today and hooked it upto safari developer tools and got the follow error.

```
Error: Can't find variable: $
```

My controllers etc work fine here however my `postLogin()` function does not.

Here is a cutdown version of my LoginController, Am i not passing $ correctly?

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($http, $ionicLoading, $scope, $state) {
        $scope.login = {};
        $scope.handlerLogin = function(response){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            if(response.data.response == 1){
                localStorage.setItem("token",response.data.token);
                $state.go("app.search", {}, {reload: true});
            }else if(response.data.response == 0){
                $scope.login.password = '';
                $('#errorMessageText').text('Login failed. Please try again.');
                $('#errorMessage').fadeIn(2000, function(){$('#errorMessage').fadeOut('slow');});
            }else{
                //handle general error?
            }
        }
        $scope.postLogin = function() {
        $ionicLoading.show({
                           template: 'loading'
                           });
        var formdata = $scope.login;
        var url = api + 'api/login';
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: url,
               data: formdata,
               success: function success(data){
               $scope.handlerLogin(data);
               },
               dataType: 'jsonp'
               });
        };
        $scope.doLogin = function() {
            if($scope.login.email == null || $scope.login.password == null){
                $('#errorMessageText').text('Please complete both fields.');
                $('#errorMessage').fadeIn(2000, function(){$('#errorMessage').fadeOut('slow');});
            }
            else{
                $scope.postLogin();
            }
        }
        });
```

Please ignore than im using `JSONP` for logging in for now.

Any pointers would be a great help! Scratching my head for hours now!!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use $ to reference jQuery. Have you included jQuery? Also, you are already including `$http`, so you can make your network calls with that instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: omg, thank you. FACEPALM moment. I've been lazy and loading jQuery over google CDN which i can't do on iOS. I've included it the app and ref'd it locally and now working all good. Thank you!